# An XHR call is it a macrotask or a microtask?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

Ajax calls are they scheduled as microtasks or macrotasks ?

And is there any difference between browsers.

Comment: Where did you learn about micro- vs macrotasks that didn't explain this?

Comment: I looked quickly here https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/  but I didn't found the response. And when I revised  this book https://www.manning.com/books/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja-second-edition, I found the respone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja, 2nd Edition, the author state that the Network events are scheduled as Macrotasks.

So, an XHR callback is queued with Macrotasks.

Comment: AFAIK, it's scheduled as macrotask